# Azure DevOps: Don't set Task status as Closed when Pull request is merged

Tags: azure-devops

I'm using Azure DevOps for both planning and coding,
Now when PR with attached issue (task)is merged, task is set to "Closed" automatically (I use project template based on Agile)
Is there a way to change it, e.g. I'd like my custom status "Ready for deploy" to be set instead of "Closed"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is currently controlled by the [PR Compeltion Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/auto-complete-work-items-pull-requests?view=azure-devops):

[image: PR Completion Settings]

Unfortunately, the (feature) you're looking for is not presently supported, you can't handle the work item state when you check "*Complete linked work item after merging*"

Here is a related **UserVoice** in Microsoft Developer Community site: [Customize Work Item State after PR is closed](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365704/customize-work-item-state-after-pr-is-closed.html).

You can vote up and add your comment there. This User Voice is already Under Review.

As workaround you could try to use [Service Hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/webhooks) to get the PR event and change the work item state to what you want.